Strapi v5 Cron Task: strapi.db.query().create Not Working as Expected
I created a background task that periodically requests an API service in cron-task in strapi v5.
I made it insert data into the DB to simply test this service, but it doesn't work well.
I confirmed that the task is called periodically, and there is no error message,
but strapi.db.query().create doesn't seem to work.
// src/api/my-data/services/my-datat.ts
import { factories, Core } from '@strapi/strapi';
export default factories.createCoreController('api::my-data.my-data', ({ strapi }: { strapi: Core.Strapi }) => ({
  async test() {
    try {
      strapi.log.debug('my-data service test');
      await strapi.db.query('api::my-data.my-data').create({
        data: {
          boardId: 12,
          cate: 'test',
          title: 'test',
          link: 'test',
          datetime: new Date().toISOString(),
          comments: 1,
        },
      });
  }
}));

// in cron-task.ts
export default {
  // *    *    *    *    *    *
  // ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬
  // │    │    │    │    │    |
  // │    │    │    │    │    └ day of week (0 - 7) (0 or 7 is Sun)
  // │    │    │    │    └───── month (1 - 12)
  // │    │    │    └────────── day of month (1 - 31)
  // │    │    └─────────────── hour (0 - 23)
  // │    └──────────────────── minute (0 - 59)
  // └───────────────────────── second (0 - 59, OPTIONAL)
  adddata: {
    task: async ({ strapi }) => {
      strapi.log.debug('Running data task...');
      const myDataService = strapi.service('api::my-data.my-data');
      await myDataService.test();
    },
    options: {
      rule: "*/1 * * * *",
    },
  },
};


you have an issues with your setup:
// src/api/my-data/services/my-datat.ts // You are pointing to a service here
import { factories, Core } from '@strapi/strapi';
export default factories.createCoreController // You are creating a controller not a service

also you have misspell here:
// src/api/my-data/services/my-datat.ts
my-data and my-datat.ts
That is likely a misspell, but I have to mention that coreService and plain service are a bit different things.
Basically coreService should be defined only once per api
So:
// src/api/my-data/services/my-data.ts
import { factories } from "@strapi/strapi";

export default factories.createCoreService(
  "api::my-data.my-data",
  ({ strapi }) => ({
    async test(ctx) {
      return strapi.db.query("api::my-data.my-data").create({
        data: {
          test: Date.now(),
        },
      });
    },
  })
);

// config/tasks.ts
export default {
  myJob: {
    task: async ({ strapi }) => {
      console.log("TASK");

      const data = await strapi.service("api::my-data.my-data").test();

      console.log({ data });
    },
    options: {
      rule: "*/1 * * * *",
    },
  },
};

// config/server.ts
import tasks from "./tasks";

export default ({ env }) => ({
  host: env("HOST", "0.0.0.0"),
  port: env.int("PORT", 1337),
  app: {
    keys: env.array("APP_KEYS"),
  },
  cron: {
    enabled: true,
    tasks,
  },
});

Output:
TASK
{
  data: {
    id: 1,
    documentId: 'ry4qjid87l3jt0pusu7t4czm',
    test: '1735200900022',
    createdAt: '2024-12-26T08:15:00.023Z',
    updatedAt: '2024-12-26T08:15:00.023Z',
    publishedAt: '2024-12-26T08:15:00.025Z',
    locale: null
  }
}


I solved it. The problem is that in v5 version, strapi.document is used instead of strapi.db.query.

Well you can use both actually, anyways document service is recommended. And check that you don’t have createCoreController in service file
